# es6 Javascript class using this inside a callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

The new es6 class allows you to use the self reference variable `this` inside methods.
However if a class method has a sub function or a callback, that function/callback no longer has access to the self reference variable `this`

```
class ClassName {
  constructor(dir){
    this.dir = dir;
    fs.access(this.dir, fs.F_OK | fs.W_OK, this.canReadDir);//nodejs fs.access with callback
  }

  canReadDir(err){
    this.dir;// NO ACCESS to class reference of this
  }
  //OR
  aMethod(){
    function aFunc(){
      this.dir;// NO ACCESS to class reference of this
    }
  }
}
```

Is there any solution to this?

Comment: You may create an arrow function instead `const aFunc = () => this.dir;`

Comment: Use [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Lexical_this).

Comment: "*The new es6 class allows you to use the self reference variable this inside methods.*" - uh, no, this has nothing to do with ES6 `class` syntax. The `this` keyword works like it always did in methods.

Comment: it's not really a duplicate as this is related to the es6 class and not just callback

Comment: Whether you use a class or not doesn't matter. A function is a function, no matter how it was created. The solutions in the answer you accepted are exactly the same as he ones suggested in the duplicate.

Comment: @FelixKling It is not just related to callback, but to sub function in a class method. I do believe anyone using es6 class may stumble upon the same issue

Comment: If you are talking about the `aMethod` example, you'd have the same issue if you did `var obj = {aMethod: function() { ... }}`. Again, the issue you are experiencing has nothing to do with classes specifically. It's just how functions work in JavaScript. And I think it's very important to point that out. People should not mistakenly think, like you seem to, that class methods are different in this regard. Rather, people have to learn how functions, and `this`, work in general.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You have the following options:

1. Use an **arrow** function:

```js
class ClassName {
  // ...
  aMethod(){
    const aFun = () => {
      this.dir// ACCESS to class reference of this
    }
  }
}
```

2. Or the `bind()` method:

```js
class ClassName {
  // ...
  aMethod(){
    var aFun = function() {
      this.dir;// ACCESS to class reference of this
    }.bind(this);
  }
}
```

3. Store `this` in a specialised variable:

```
class ClassName {
  // ...
  aMethod(){
    var self = this;
    function aFun() {
      self.dir;// ACCESS to class reference of this
    }
  }
}
```

[This article](https://dmitripavlutin.com/gentle-explanation-of-this-in-javascript/) describes the necessary details about `this` and arrow functions in JavaScript.

Comment: Isn't self a preserved word?

Comment: @Bálint Nope. `self` can be used.

Comment: second options works well, using arrow also works

Comment: How would you write the 
canReadDir(err) 
function (just to make the example complete)?

Comment: The `bind()` method works very well and its easy to read (y)

Comment: finally I found the difference between the `function` and the `=>` syntax, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Put a reference to dir in aMethod(), then use that in aFunc like

```
aMethod() {
    var tempDir = this.dir;
    aFunc() {
        console.log(tempDir);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use of `var self = this;` or `var that = this;` and using that later is already a pretty well understood practice for that purpose.